# Is there any way to get background <audio> to work anymore?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, autoplay

I have tried:

- the standard: audio autoplay
- the standard plus controls: audio autoplay controls
- NOT having autoplay in the audio element and starting it later with
  audio.play() in an auto exec script.

I'm out of ideas.

Note: This is just chromes fault, as it works in every other browser.

Comment: With new versions of chrome the user must interact with the webpage before any audio can start playing.

Comment: I read the same thing, but no matter what i do on my website it never plays. Playing Videos, clicking links, downloading files, Nothing!